# how does mongodb store data?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have read several articles but it is still not clear. I want to know how mongodb store document in memory and disk. Does it store a whole document as a string in memory, or like a map structure?

Answer (score 1):

A given mongo database is broken up into a series of BSON files on disk, with increasing size up to 2GB. BSON is its own format, built specifically for MongoDB.

These slides should answer all of your questions:

http://www.slideshare.net/mdirolf/inside-mongodb-the-internals-of-an-opensource-database

In future posts, please ask a specific question or error you have and include any related pieces of code and error messages.Thank You :)